# Can I set the z-order of painted GMarker with Subgurim Maps?

Tags: google-maps, subgurim-maps

I'm painting some GMarkers on a map with Subgurim Map control.

Sometimes the GMarkers overlap each other. That isn't a problem, but I want one specific one, which is kwown when I put it on the map, on top of all the others because that is the one the user clicked latest.

I thought I could just add it to the map as the latest one and it would be on top, but it isn't: the z-order of it looks like to be set at random.

Can I make sure that this GMarker is 'painted on top'?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Maps itself, you can set the z-index of the markers by specifying a {zIndexProcess} parameter when you create them.

The default z-index value is calculated from the latitude. Markers to the south appear on top. The default z-index values can be very large positive and negative values, so your zIndexProcess code needs to use extremely large z-index values to be guaranteed to be on top.

See: [This tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/zindex.htm)

I don't know whether using subgurim affects your access to {zIndexProcess}.